# PreventDefault() with named function and function parameter

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add an e.preventDefault() call to my event listener. My function call "voteNoClick" needs to pass a parameter ("direction"). How do I pass both the direction parameter and the event object into the function so I can then add e.preventDefault() within the function? When I try to add the event "e" as a parameter in addition to "direction" it seems to think e is an ordinary parameter.

Thanks in advance!

```
document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', voteNoClick(direction));
```

```
function voteNoClick(direction) {
       // I want to add e.preventDefault() here
        document.getElementById("voteMessageID").innerHTML = "Waiting for the votes to be tallied...";
        voteResults('no',direction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return another function inside it and you can access event like this.

```
function voteNoClick(direction) {
    return function(event){
    // your code ...
        event.preventDefault()
        document.getElementById("voteMessageID").innerHTML = "Waiting for the votes to be tallied...";
        voteResults('no',direction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can try this

```
document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', (e) => voteNoClick(e, direction));

function voteNoClick(e, direction) {
 e.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById("voteMessageID").innerHTML = "Waiting for the votes to be tallied...";
 voteResults('no',direction);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Pierre. This solved my problem temporarily, but I couldn't call the event later in a `removeEventListener()` call because I couldn't use the anonymous function -- I needed a named function to do that. Your answer worked in solving my question, thank you. But just noting for anyone else who stumbles upon this... when I needed to remove the event later, I ran into difficulties.

Comment: Hello back, I don't know where "direction" come from but maybe u can define before the callback of eventlistener :

const handleClick = (e) => voteNoClick(e, direction)
document.getElementById('voteButtonNoID').addEventListener('click', handleClick);

End next u can remove with
document.removeEventListener('click',handleClick)